# How to select the pagination number from list which is dynamically generated?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is the code for generating the pagination

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <c:forEach items="${pegination}" var="vi">
    <li><a href="#"  id="getit" class="block2-sid">${vi.num}</a></li>
  c:forEach>     
</ul>
```

This is the code for selecting from it

```
$('.pagination').click(function () {
  var ty = $(this).index();
  var tu = document.getElementsByClassName('.block2-sid')[ty].innerHTML;
  alert(' value ' + tu);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work
```

```
$('.pagination').click(function (event) {
  var ty = $(this).index();
  var tu = event.target.innerHTML;
  alert(' value ' + tu);
});
```

```